# Create a file in a Docker image during a Gitlab build

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Gitlab CI where it build a Docker image, push it the Gitlab Registry and then pull and start it on a server.

Problem is my application needs a `.env` file. As I don't want to commit this file, I thought I'd create it during the build. But I can't manage to do it.

Here's what I already tried :

1 - Setting all the different variables as Gitlab environment variables and using a bash script to create the `.env` file with the one stored in Gitlab

```
deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - chmod +x ./scripts/setup_env.sh
    - ./scripts/setup_env.sh
```

```
#!/bin/bash

echo NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY=$NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY >> .env
echo NEXT_PUBLIC_APOLLO_BROWSER_URL=$NEXT_PUBLIC_APOLLO_BROWSER_URL >> .env
echo NEXT_PUBLIC_APOLLO_SERVER_URL=$NEXT_PUBLIC_APOLLO_SERVER_URL >> .env
echo NEXT_PUBLIC_APOLLO_PROD_URL=$NEXT_PUBLIC_APOLLO_PROD_URL >> .env
```

2 - Storing the whole `.env` as a file variable on Gitlab and copying it directly

```
deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - echo "$ENV_FILE" > ./.env
```

But with either solution, same result: the `.env` file is nowhere to be seen. Even if in the build logs, all seems fine.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a file to be in your docker image, your Dockerfile needs to copy that file from the context to the image it is building. That said since your file is actually a `.env` I don't think it makes sense to have it inside the image.

When using the [Docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) from GitLab, every job is run in a new container. Meaning that unless you have a volume map between your host and the actual runner, the env file will not persist.

Our usual setup for docker deployments is to have a folder say `/opt/project` which is mapped to the runner. The deployment job writes the `.env` in this folder. The `.env` file is then used by the container.

As a side note, you can use CI secrets set in GitLab's UI to add secrets to the `.env` file. If for any reason you don't want to use CI secrets, you can manually setup the env file directly in the server.

Comment: Thanks, I tried you setup with mapping a folder to the runner and everything seems fine now